# Как очистить обтекание после псевдоэлемента :after?

Tags: css

Есть список, где в каждом пункте меню присутствуют стрелочки справа, которые я поместил с помощью `float`.

Вопрос: как очистить обтекание после псевдокласса?

Вот код:

```css
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu>li.cat-item>a:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Name 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @lexxl после `:after` невозможно расположить никаких блоков. Он по умолчанию последний

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текущем варианте ваших стилей — никак.

Теперь поясню почему.

Дело в том, что `:after` и задумывался как последний (псевдо-)элемент.
После него ничего по определению быть не может.

Отсюда делаем вывод, что нужно сменить подход.
Например, стилизуем с помощью псевдоэлемента `:before`, а затем очищаем обтекание с помощью псевдоэлемента `:after`.

Вот ваш исправленный пример css:

```
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a:before {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

---

Как вариант, обтекание можно очистить на родительском элементе. Например, вот так:

```
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a {
  overflow: auto; /* очищает обтекание */
}
.menu > li.cat-item > a:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: точно! как же сам не додумался)